# jquery unobtrusive validation not using data-val attributes?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation

I have a form using jquery validation, generated by ASP.NET tag helpers:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Id, new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Which generates:

```
<form id="dsForm">       
    <label class="control-label" for="Id">Rule ID</label>
    <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Rule ID must be a string with a minimum length of 3 and a maximum length of 100." data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length-min="3" data-val-required="Rule ID is required." id="Id" maxlength="100" name="Id" type="text" value="">
    <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Id" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>    
</form>
```

I'm trying to invoke the jquery validation using:

```
<a onclick="dsValidate()">Validate</a>

<script>
    function dsValidate() {
        $('#dsForm').validate();

        if ($('#dsForm').valid() === true) {
            console.log("valid");
        } else {
            console.log("invalid");
        }
    }
</script>
```

However, this is always logging "valid", even when the input violates the rules in the `data-val` attributes.

If I define the rules directly in the javascript, it works:

```
$('#dsForm').validate({
    rules: {
        Id: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 100
        }
    },
    messages: {
        Id: {
            required: "ID is required.",
            minlength: "ID must be 3-100 chars.",
            maxlength: "ID must be 3-100 chars."
        }
    }                
});
```

Why is the `validate()` function not recognizing the rules defined in the `data-val` attributes?

I have confirmed the necessary jquery libraries are loaded in order:

```
<script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this line to the javascript function prior to calling validate:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#dsForm'));
```

I believe this was necessary due to the fact that my form is populated dynamically prior to validation.